# How can I calculate optimal controls and sample trajectories in a stochastic optimal control problem?

Tags: optimization, stochastic-processes, matlab, random-walk, control-theory

I'm trying to replicate Figure 3 of this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0411119v2.pdf) in order to observe the symmetry breaking that implies a 'delayed choice' mechanism. There is a formula for $u$ (optimal control), but how can I calculate this as a function of time in order to observe what happens when we vary $v,T$ ? What are the steps that someone has to follow in order to obtain the Figure 3?

Any ideas/suggestions of how I can go deeper into this would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I can not enter the paper!?

Comment: @JanEerland You are right, I updated the link.

Comment: I see it, thanks! Are you from The Netherlands? Because you're reading a paper by a famous Dutch doctor.